# How to prevent Line breaks for fo:page-number-citation

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

XSL-FO processor - Apache FOP.

There is a very simple xsl-fo with Table of Contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2.5cm" margin-right="2.5cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>Block with fixed page number:</fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>1</fo:block>
            <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page:</fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
            <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to non-existing page:</fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_zzz"/></fo:block>
            <fo:block id="id_test"/>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

First ToC line contains fixed text in the page number position.

Second ToC line contains `fo:page-number-citation` to block's id on page 1.

Third ToC line contains `fo:page-number-citation` to non-existing block's id.

As you can see on picture, second ToC line contains line break. How to prevent it?
Looks like Apache FOP reserves some space for page number (see 3rd ToC line), but is it possible to decrease this space?

[image: Rendering example]

**Update:**
I've added the property `text-align="justify"`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2.5cm" margin-right="2.5cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block-container border-right="1pt solid red">
                <fo:block>Block with fixed page number:</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>1</fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page:</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page (text-align="justify):</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify" text-align="justify">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page (text-align="justify):</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify" text-align="justify">Test1: Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page (text-align="justify):</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify" text-align="justify">Test2: Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page (text-align="justify):</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify" text-align="justify">Test3: Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page (text-align="justify):</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify" text-align="justify">Test4: Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block>Block with page-number-citation to existing page (text-align="justify):</fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify" text-align="justify">Test5: Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id_test"/></fo:block>
                <fo:block>&#xa0;</fo:block>
                <fo:block id="id_test"/>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

but it has a side effect - page numbers sometimes don't aligned right (it depends on length of text):
[image]

Comment: How about applying `text-align="justify"` with `text-align-last="justify"` to second relevant `fo:block`?

Comment: @tmakita it works but not always, sometimes page number don't aligned right. I've updated post.

Comment: Could you add (or attach) your exiting test data once again?

Comment: @tmakita post updated.

Comment: I got the same result with FOP 2.6. But I got the desired result with AH Formatter. See snapshot from One Drive. This may be the FOP bug. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkbL99fLhxKUh7Q6J1LbLcsrvDuVIw?e=eGv92p